# pygame.sprite.collision Not executing at correct position

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently taking an A level computer science course in which I have to create a game for a project. I know this code is probably not efficient but I am trying to keep it to my own work and would like a hand with one bit that I am confused on.

This code currently creates a sprite for a Robot and for a Platform and I am trying to work out the collision between the two. At the moment, they do collide but only when the Robot's top touches the bottom of the platform, at which point it is no longer on the screen.

The collision is working but the rect's that are currently used must be misplaced or not working

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame as pg
import time
import random

pg.init()#initiates pygame

display_height = 690#Creates width and height of screen
display_width = 1024
#Colours
white = (255,255,255) 
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
sky = (73,71,65) # grey

Robot_height = 100#Height of robot
Robot_width = 112 #Width of robot
lives = 3 #Robot Lives
Bullet_Fired = False
PowerUp_Active = False
Robot_acc = 0.3 #Robot Acceleration
vec = pg.math.Vector2

gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height)) #Sets display properties of window
pg.display.set_caption ("Game") #Title on window
clock = pg.time.Clock()
robotImg = pg.image.load("robot1.png") #Loads robots image

#Class for platforms
class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x,y,w,h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w,h))
        self.image.fill(blue)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

#class for robot
class RobotClass(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((Robot_width,Robot_height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (display_width / 2, display_height / 2)
        self.RobotPos = vec(display_width / 2, display_height / 2)
        self.bottom = (0,0)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0.005)

#creates platform 1
p1 = Platform(0,display_height - 40,display_width,40)

#creates a sprite group for platforms
platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
#Adds platform 1
platforms.add(p1)

#game loop
def game_loop():
    Robot = RobotClass()
    Robot_friction = -0.3 #Friction value
    vec = pg.math.Vector2 #Setting vec as vector quantity
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit
                quit()
            #Starts acceleration when key is pressed
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    Robot.acc.x = -Robot_acc
                elif event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    Robot.acc.x = Robot_acc
            #Adds friction to accleration to slow robot down when key is not being pressed
            if event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT or event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    Robot.acc.x = Robot.acc.x * Robot_friction

        #Adjusts velocity of robot by adding the acceleration on each cycle
        Robot.vel = Robot.vel+ Robot.acc
        #Fills background
        gameDisplay.fill(sky)
        #Draws the platform p1 to the screen
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, (p1))
        #Changes Robot position according to its velocity,acceleration and the friction
        Robot.RobotPos = Robot.RobotPos + Robot.vel + 0.5 * Robot.acc
        #Loads robot onto screen
        gameDisplay.blit(robotImg,(Robot.RobotPos))
        #Updates display
        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

        #Sets bottom of robot to its position
        Robot.rect.midbottom =  Robot.RobotPos

        #Collision detection
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(Robot , platforms, False)
        if hits:
            print ("Collision")
            #Puts Robot on top of platform
            Robot.RobotPos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            Robot.vel.y = 0

        #Sets top velocity of robot    
        if Robot.vel.x > 6:
            Robot.vel.x = 6
        if Robot.vel.x < -6:
            Robot.vel.x = -6
        #Makes robot velocity = 0 when it is close to 0
        if Robot.vel.x < 0.05 and Robot.vel.x > -0.05:
            Robot.acc.x = 0
            Robot.vel.x = 0


game_loop()
pg.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Regarding variable names, functions, variables, instances and attributes should have lowercase names with underscores (snake_case). Upper and camelcase is for classes.

Comment: Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get more suggestions or improvement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to draw the rect of the Robot and you'll see what's wrong.

```
pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, Robot.rect, 2)
```

You're blitting the image at the wrong position. `Robot.RobotPos` is the midbottom pos of the rect, because you do `Robot.rect.midbottom = Robot.RobotPos`. Blit the image at the rect's topleft position instead: `gameDisplay.blit(Robot.image, Robot.rect)`. If the rect and image have different sizes, you have to adjust the blit position.

Comment: Thanks that worked now i just need to adjust size of image to what it actually is. Thanks for help :)